# Understanding OpenCV Hierarchies

Tags: opencv, hierarchy

New to OpenCV here.  I'm trying to understand what a hierarchy vector is supposed to contain.  I understand that for object tracking and when using the findCountours function, it is common to use vector, but I would like to understand what this means.  Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A contour is a closed edge around an area of an image. This contour could contain contours so we need a way to store this hierarchy. The hierarchy vector contains all of the information to explain how contours are nested in each other.

From the OpenCV [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=findcontours#findcontours) it is a

> Optional output vector, containing information about the image topology. It has as many elements as the number of contours. For each i-th contour contours[i] , the elements hierarchy[i][0] , hiearchy[i][1] , hiearchy[i][2] , and hiearchy[i][3] are set to 0-based indices in contours of the next and previous contours at the same hierarchical level, the first child contour and the parent contour, respectively. If for the contour i there are no next, previous, parent, or nested contours, the corresponding elements of hierarchy[i] will be negative.

You can think of this as a doubly linked list, but each item in the list points could possibly point to a parent and/or child. We can use the next and previous indices to find all of the contours that have the same parent. Each contour will point to a child linked list if they contain a child contour. A negative value is the same as a `NULL` pointer for a traditional linked list.

```
An example:
a
|
b,c,d,e,f
|     |
g     h,i
```

`a` points to `b` as one child and from `b` we know that `b`, `c`, `d`, `e`, and `f` are all contained at the same level in `a`. `b` also has a child contour `g`. `e` has two children as well.